# Getting Error in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know this is basic question.Need help getting error in List using foreach storing data in List but in the end it give me error that `_obj` does not exist in the context

I have ActionResult Page

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var _objAdd = new C();
    var Get_ClientInfor = example();

    foreach (var item in Get_ClientInfor)
    {
        var _obj = new List<C>();

        _objAdd.FirstName = item.Clients.FirstName;
        _objAdd.LastName = item.Clients.LastName;
        if (item.Clients.DateBirth != null)
            _objAdd.Dob = item.Clients.DateBirth.Value;
        _objAdd.Gender = item.ClientDemographics.Gender;


        _obj.Add(_objAdd);
    }

    return View(_obj); //error ===>>>
}
```

Getting Error that `_obj` does not exist in the context.

Comment: move `var _obj = new List<C>();` outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap `_objAdd` and `_obj` declarations because `_objAdd` is an item you want to add to collection in `foreach` loop and `_obj` is a collection you want to return:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var _obj = new List<C>();
    var Get_ClientInfor = example();

    foreach (var item in Get_ClientInfor)
    {
        var _objAdd = new C();

        _objAdd.FirstName = item.Clients.FirstName;
        _objAdd.LastName = item.Clients.LastName;
        if (item.Clients.DateBirth != null)
            _objAdd.Dob = item.Clients.DateBirth.Value;
        _objAdd.Gender = item.ClientDemographics.Gender;


        _obj.Add(_objAdd);
    }


    return View(_obj);
}
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. Beat me by 10 seconds it seems.

Comment: getting issue then actually.. Let suppose Get_ClientInfor() have 20 rows. it add all 20 rows to _obt but all 20 rows have the same data mean firstname last name .because it convert the 20 rows to the last rows data – Agha 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: @Agha, try my example it solves that issue is I get you point right.

Answer (score 3):

You put the _obj variable on foreach. Your need to declare outside the iteration. Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Get_ClientInfor = example();
    var _obj = new List<C>();

    foreach (var item in Get_ClientInfor)
    {
        var _objAdd = new C();
        _objAdd.FirstName = item.Clients.FirstName;
        _objAdd.LastName = item.Clients.LastName;
        if (item.Clients.DateBirth != null)
        {
            _objAdd.Dob = item.Clients.DateBirth.Value;
        }
        _objAdd.Gender = item.ClientDemographics.Gender;
        _obj.Add(_objAdd);
    }


    return View(_obj)
}
```

Comment: getting issue then actually.. Let suppose Get_ClientInfor() have 20 rows. it add all 20 rows to _obt but all 20 rows have the same data mean firstname last name .because it convert the 20 rows to the last rows data

Comment: You need to change location of new C(). If you declare _objAdd outside the foreach, object orientation change all references. Try copy all my code than you see that I created new _objAdd for each "item" inside foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Move the declaration of `_obj` outside the `foreach` loop.
The lexical scope of variable `_obj` is inside the scope defined by the braces `{}`. So, the variable  _obj is not accessible outside the loop. Once you move the variable outside, it is accessible at the Index method level.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var Get_ClientInfor = example();

    var _obj = new List<C>();
    foreach (var item in Get_ClientInfor)
    {
        var _objAdd = new C();
        _objAdd.FirstName = item.Clients.FirstName;
        _objAdd.LastName = item.Clients.LastName;
        if (item.Clients.DateBirth != null)
        {
            _objAdd.Dob = item.Clients.DateBirth.Value;
        }
        _objAdd.Gender = item.ClientDemographics.Gender;

        _obj.Add(_objAdd);
    }
    return View(_obj);//error ===>>
}
```

Comment: getting issue then actually.. Let suppose Get_ClientInfor() have 20 rows. it add all 20 rows to _obt but all 20 rows have the same data mean firstname last name .because it convert the 20 rows to the last rows data – Agha 2 mins ago    edit

Comment: `_obj` is created on  each iteration from the `item` so they can't be the same. Untill `Get_ClientInfor` contains reference to same data. Could you post more code which is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

You put the _obj variable on foreach, you will only be able to use it in the method. Your need to declare outside the iteration.